# Using Xcode 5 Storyboards to Build Dynamic TableViews with Prototype Table View Cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to follow this tutorial but I am getting empty table.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_5_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells

First, tutorial is using

```
{
CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
      forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

with this I have encountered an error:

```
2013-11-12 11:29:35.940 TableViewStory[14940:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with 
identifier carTableCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a 
prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

So I added:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[CarTableViewCell class] 
    forCellReuseIdentifier:@"carTableCell"];
```

on my viewDidLoad. After adding the registerClass I was able to build my application. However I am getting empty table.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you give your cell an identifier in the storyboard? If so, make sure it's spelled correctly. You shouldn't need to register a class (an in fact you shouldn't) if you've designed your cell in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-did the tutorial and everything worked.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath method appropriately:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

// Customize your cell

return cell;
}
```

You didn't register a nib or a class for the reuse identifier CellIdentifier. You are using below piece

```
CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
      forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Replace this with

```
CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: Hi, I did add a tableView registerClass method on my viewDidLoad method. And also tried using this method above which still gives me an empty table. 

Thanks

Comment: Let me correct that, when I use

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
I get this error:

2013-11-12 14:43:47.062 TableViewStory[15135:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack: